# How to find $P$ such that $D=P^{-1}AP$ if $A$ has multiple parameters?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> It is given that matrix $A$: $$
> A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1\\0&1&b\\0&0&c\end{pmatrix}  
> $$
>   is diagonizable if $c \neq 1$. There're two eigenvalues are $t_1=1$ and $t_2=c\neq 1$. Find the matrix $P$ such that $D=P^{-1}AP$.

As far as I understand I need to find the general solution to the following system:
$$
tI-A=\begin{pmatrix} t-1&0&-1\\0&t-1&-b\\0&0&t-c\end{pmatrix}  
$$
If $t_1=1$ then we get:
$$
I-A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&-1\\0&0&-b\\0&0&1-c\end{pmatrix}  
$$
After row reduction I'd get only one row which means that the eigenspace $V_{t_1}=span\{(0,0,1)\}$.

Also if $t_2=c$ then we get:
$$
cI-A=\begin{pmatrix} c-1&0&-1\\0&c-1&-b\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}  
$$

So $b=c-1$ then:
$$
cI-A=\begin{pmatrix} b&0&-1\\0&b&-b\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}  
$$
which would mean that the eigenspace $V_{t_2}=span\{(1,1,1)\}$

What am I doing **wrong**? Please provide feedback on the method I'm using to find $P$ (though solving the corresponding homogeneous system of linear equations).

Comment: $$P = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{c-1} \\
 1 & 0 & \dfrac{b}{c-1} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Moo This is the special case for $p_{11}=p_{22}=0$, $p_{13}=1/(c-1)$ and $p_{21}=p_{12}=1$ below.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Although your statement is true, I think the OP wants to use his/her (albeit harder) approach and this result is more in-line with that.

Comment: @Moo Yes, of course. I just wanted to say that we agree on the result.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Indeed - you gave a very nice solution (+1).

Comment: @Moo you're just giving the solution. But can you please tell me why when I substituted $t$ for $1$ everything went to pieces?

Comment: If you end up with one non-zero row after row reduction, it means that the null space is *two*-dimensional. You’ve pulled out a basis for the *row* space of the matrix instead.

Comment: You really shouldn’t have $A=$ all over the place, since these are all matrices different from the original $A$ in the problem.

Comment: @amd I changed the names thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite this as a matrix equation $PD=AP$ with $D=diag(1,1,c)$, $A$ as given, and an invertible matrix $P=(p_{ij})$. This gives linear equations in the unknowns $p_{ij}$ which can be solved by Gauss elimination as usual. The matrix $P$ need not be unique in general. Also, one has to check $\det(P)\neq 0$, of course.

From the $9$ linear equations I obtain that
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} \cr p_{21} & p_{22} & bp_{13} \cr
0 & 0 & (c-1)p_{13} \end{pmatrix}
$$
Now I can choose an invertible one, e.g.,
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 & b \cr
0 & 0 & (c-1)\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you please show the solution for at least one eigenvalue, for example, $t_1=1$?

Comment: I don't need any eigenvalues. They are already given in $A$, i.e., in $D$. I just solve $PD=AP$ for $P$. Then $D=P^{-1}AP$.

Comment: But as I mentioned in the OP I want to understand what is wrong with my method. The method is to plug in the eigenvalue instead of $t$ and solve the system. But I'm doing something wrong: either solving the system incorrectly or plugging in incorrectly

Comment: Or using a "wrong" method, instead of an easy one. I don't understand why you compute $A$. Your title says "how to find $P$"?

Comment: I did try using your method but I still don't understand how you got from $$
P=\begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} \cr p_{21} & p_{22} & bp_{13} \cr
0 & 0 & (c-1)p_{13} \end{pmatrix}
$$ to $$
P=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 1 & b \cr
0 & 0 & (c-1)\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @Yos Oh, this is easy. The parameters $p_{ij}$ are arbitrary, except that we need to have $\det(P)\neq 0$. So I choose $p_{11}=p_{22}=p_{13}=1$ and so on. The (nice) solution of Moo has another choice.

Comment: I'm sorry but even though this may be an easier method but I can't use it in my course as a) I don't like to guess that the determinant be not zero (there may be much more complicated examples) b) this technique was not proven in my course (I don't have any theorem that allows me to choose arbitrary values for $P$). As a result it's always nice to learn new approaches but still I would like to understand why when I substitute $t=1$ I get can't get to the correct solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61231/discussion-between-yos-and-dietrich-burde).

Comment: a) The determinant of an upper-triangular $P$ is the product of the diagonal elements, so you don't have to guess. b) It is not about what you have proven in a course. It is about understanding something. This is why you have asked the question here. Otherwise just ask your instructor.

Comment: Exactly, I want to understand what is wrong my method. And I explicitly mentioned this in my question.

Comment: But you know already what is wrong. The system $t\cdot id-A$ is not what you want. This is only the eigenvalues, i.e., the polynomial $\det(t\cdot id-A)$.

Comment: I just realized that, that's exactly my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you’re doing wrong is misinterpreting the result of row-reduction. The eigenspace of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the *null space* of $\lambda I-A$. So, when you end up with $$\pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$$ that doesn’t mean that the eigenspace of $1$ is spanned by $(0,0,1)^T$—that’s a basis for the *row* space of the matrix. The eigenspace of $1$ is instead spanned by $(1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0)^T$.

Similarly, when calculating the eigenspace of $c$, you want the *null space* of $cI-A$, which you can read directly from the matrix. It’s already in echelon form with pivots in the first and second columns, so a basis for the null space will come from the third column: $(1/(1-c),b/(1-c),-1)^T$ or, more conveniently, $(1,b,c-1)^T$.

Note that in this case you didn’t have to go through this process to find the eigenspace of $1$. You know that it’s at most two-dimensional, since you have another distinct eigenvalue of $A$. Recalling that the columns of a matrix are the images of the basis, you can see that both $(1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0)$ are mapped to themselves by $A$, so there’s your basis for the eigenspace.

Comment: I understand that $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ are immediate. But why does $(1,b,c)$ become $(1/(1-c), b/(1-c), -1)$ and eventually $(1,b,c-1)$?

Comment: @Yos Do you to understand how to get a basis for the null space of a matrix from its rref? If not, it would be a good idea to review that because you’re going to have to do it all the time to compute eigenvectors.

Comment: @Yos As for $(1/(1-c),b/(1-c),-1)\to(1,b,c-1)$, that’s just multiplying the vector by $1-c$. Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, after all.